# How to pass a List or specific looped list to firebase doc in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to achieve a task in which I have a `List<dynamic>`and its giving me multiple values on its indexes e.g. `['Me','Admin', so on....]` something like this.
I cannot pass the List directly to Document ID it gives index error and I don't if it will still give error or not If the List give data in string `List<String>`

I want to loop around the indexes of this list and pass it to Firebase collection's document id to get multiple data's of the users. For example on list's index 0 there's `Me` coming for myself and on index 1 there's `Admin` coming. Both have their respective data stored in Firestore collection with their own document id's Me and Admin. I want it to be checked on the runtime the app will check if its Me or Admin or Some other index value

Here's my code of the list and the firestore I'm trying to achieve.

```
List<dynamic> clientcodes = [];
 void getclientcodes() async {
    final clientcode = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
        .get()
        .then((clientcode) {
      return clientcode.data()!["clientcode"];
    });
    setState(() {
      if (clientcode != null) {
        clientcodes = clientcode;
      } else if (clientcode == null) {
        setState(() {
          const SpinKitSpinningLines(size: 100, color: Color(0xFF25315B));
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Firestore:

```
Future getdatastatus() async {
    DocumentSnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Statements")
        // .doc("If I hardcode it the value of index 0 or 1 it works fine")
        .doc(portfolionames.toString()) // This is area of issue
        .get();
    if (result.exists) {
      print("Yes");
    } else {
      print("No");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert `getdatastatus()` inside a loop, and let it get the index automatically by comparing it with any value you want it, see this:

```
Future getdatastatus() async {
    for (var item in clientcodes) {
      String docId = item.id;
      if (docId == 'X' || docId == 'Y') {
        DocumentSnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Statements")
            .doc(docId)
            .get();
        if (result.exists) {
          print("Yes");
        } else {
          print("No");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope that work with you!!

**Update**

In the first section of your code, I think there is a problem..

You can create the list out of the firestore streaming, then add the coming data to the list of model, after that you can loop it to take the value you want.

```
Class Database{
List<TestModel> clientcodes = [];

getclientcodes() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      clientcodes.add(TestModel.fromMap(event));
      setState(() {
        if (clientcode != null) {
          clientcodes = clientcode;
        } else if (clientcode == null) {
          setState(() {
            const SpinKitSpinningLines(size: 100, color: Color(0xFF25315B));
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

class TestModel {
  late String name;
  late String description;

  TestModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
  });

  TestModel.fromMap(DocumentSnapshot data) {
    name = data['name'];
    description = data['description'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems promising but its not giving me yes or no result for some reason do you know what can be the reason? I've even tried giving it hardcoded indexes but still not giving result

Comment: Actually I thought you wrote if you hard coded it works fine !!!
Any way, recently I faced Some thing similar, and I passed it by this solution I've putted to you.
But in the first code you inserted, I think there is a problem, I will try to put it in a new reply